# using external library in C language on Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, encryption

I want to create a application in c where I can encrypt and decrypt some data I am using the following code which is on github,

https://gist.github.com/bricef/2436364

but I am not able to link mcrypt.h file, I am new to C can anyone help with this ? I am getting following error. **I am using gcc on ubuntu.**

```
    undefined reference to `mcrypt_module_open'
    aes.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `mcrypt_enc_get_block_size'
    aes.c:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `mcrypt_generic_init'
    aes.c:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `mcrypt_generic'
```

Comment: In the code you write, from which you want to access the library functions, that code must contain `mcrypt.h` to provide prototypes for the functions. The error is telling you you don't have the header included in the file with your code... You also must pass the `-lmcrypt` linker instruction telling it to link the library against your code.

Comment: You must link the library which contains fucntions listed: add `-lyour_lib` to your [tag:gcc] command.

Comment: **Please don't use mcrypt in new code.** It's an abandoned library with several bugs and bad defaults. There should be much better alternatives such as OpenSSL or other more opinionated libraries that make everything for you.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have already included mcrypt.h in /usr/local/include directory

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin can you please give me steps ? I am not able to link it

Comment: [_"The last update to libmcrypt was in 2007, despite years of unmerged patches. These facts have led security experts to declare mcrypt abandonware and discourage its use in new development. Prefer bcrypt, ccrypt, libressl, and others."_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mcrypt)

Comment: Install libmcrypt-dev using **sudo apt-get install libmcrypt-dev**
Then compile your application with this command: `gcc application.c -o application -lmcrypt`
Assuming your source file name is application.c

Comment: @Shailesh the instructions from @Gaurav should do exactly what you need. Given your error was `aes.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to 'mcrypt_enc_get_block_size'` that is the compiler telling your it cannot find the `'mcrypt_enc_get_block_size'` function. To enable the compiler to find it, you must (1) include `#include <mcrypt.h>` at the top of the code that uses the function (the actual file is `/usr/include/mcrypt.h`) and (2) link against the library by specifying `-lmcrypt` in your compile string (e.g. `gcc -Wall -o output -lmcrypt aes.c`) You need `libmcrypt-dev` installed to do that.

Comment: got it thanks..! @DavidC.Rankin